# Is having only a FK Reference preferable to having both the object reference and the FK reference?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to take advantage of what Julie Lerman calls Bounded Context. For my Domain Models I have Employee, Customer, InventoryItems, SalesOrderHeader & SalesOrderDetail. Sales Order Header has two properties:

```
public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
public virtual Employee SalesPerson { get; set; }
```

Now the Sales Order Context has no need to know the Employee’s Social Security Number nor his Salary, etc. So I created an EmployeeReference model as such:

```
[Table("Employees")]
public class EmployeeReference
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }

    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    public string FullName => string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
}
```

To make a bounded context for Sales Orders I would only include SalesOrderHeader, SalesOrderDetail, InventoryItems, Customer & EmployeeRefererence while ignoring the Employee table.

Now I get an error with my Sales Order Headers that the Employee object cannot map to null.

My solution was to Comment out the property SalesPerson in the Sales Order Header but leave the EmployeeId, then run EntityFramework migration.

Because SalesPerson property is virtual can I not just override the property? Is just having only an Id Reference preferable to having both the object reference and Id reference?

Comment: it depends on what you want actually. with keeping only the id reference, you're essentially throwing away functionality. that means you have less overhead from EF itself. However, you have to build FK relationships yourself and throw your objects together yourself, and why would you use an ORM in that case anyways.

Comment: Of course, @DevilSuichiro , I would like to keep the functionality, if possible. I am unsure if that is practical with Bounded Contexts.